# App installs not recorded in Facebook Insights

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-insights

My Android app uses Facebook SDK (updated to 3.6 version) to share some information to facebook, code as below

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this).setLink(getLink()).build();
mUiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

As I see on Facebook Insights (enabled on Settings > Advanced), app installs is not recorded even when user authorized my app. Can anyone tell me why and what's conditions to make Facebook record my app installs? Thank you.

Comment: Are you calling activateApp somewhere?

Comment: Are you including the code needed to tell Facebook about the app installs, or expecting that other actions with the API will implicitly create an 'intall' action? I don't think the latter is true

Comment: I have another app which uses Facebook log in and does not call activateApp() but device installs is still recorded, so I don't think we must call activateApp(). I also tried calling activateApp() before but it made no difference except that event fb_mobile_activate_app recorded in App Events.

Comment: @lgy: I don't include any code to tell Facebook to record app installs because I think SDK will do that. If SDK don't do it for me so what code I need to explicitly call?

Comment: @Wayne Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

activateApp is strongly recommended.

There are two basic steps:

1. Verify raw (unattributed) fires. Use Analytics for Apps: `https://www.facebook.com/analytics/[App ID]/?section=most_recent`. You can filter for Android or iOS. If there's an issue here, review the developer guide.
2. Verify attributed fires using Ads Manager. Note that the App you've verified in step 1 will need to be tracked by the relevant campaign(s).